# something that checks if my grammar is LL(1)

Tags: parsing, grammar

I'm writing a parser for a course and my grammar is rather long and I don't want to check it by hand. Is there something I can use to check if it's LL(1)?

Answer (score 1):

You could enter your grammar in any LL(1) parser generator like javaCC, ANTLR or Coco/R and try to generate a parser. If there are any conflicts it will warn you. Just make sure that the lookahead options are set to 1 which should normally be the default if that options exists.